# Propagation of transactions in Spring is flaky

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a Spring/Hibernate app that uses transactional services and I am a bit of confused how do transactions work when using NEW propagation:

```
@Transactional
method A()
    |
    |-loop for each element
       |
       |-@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
         method B()
           |-make some entity change and save()
```

So as you can see I have a loop of entities and each entity is handled in a separate method that has NEW transaction. Please confirm my assumptions:

1. If there is an exception in method B, then all changes that were done in this method should not be saved to DB when method A returns.
2. If there is NO exception in method B, then changes made in method B are COMMITTED IMMEDIATELY to DB, even though there is a parent transaction caused by method A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If there is an exception in method B, then all changes that were done in this method should not be saved to DB when method A returns.

No, changes that were already committed in method B will stay committed. For example, if you have 10 steps in loop and exception occured on step 4, changes made on step 1-3 will be saved.

> If there is NO exception in method B, then changes made in method B are COMMITTED IMMEDIATELY to DB, even though there is a parent transaction caused by method A.

Exactly

PS. Be sure that you call methodB() using Spring, not just a Java call. The simplest way is to put methodB() in another class, different from methodA(). Another way is using @Resource annotation, but it looks a bit tricky.

Comment: Great answer. But what will happen if exception happens in step 4 and it gets propagated to parent method, hence causing parent method to interrup its own transaction, would these step 1-3 items be persisted even though a parent transaction was rolled back?

Comment: Transaction in methodA is not a parent transaction, it is another transaction which has no connection to transaction in methodB. Remember, you wrote "Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW".

Comment: Thanks again, I extracted my new question to a new thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35394411/spring-and-hibernate-transaction-management-issue . I would appreciate you very much to have a look at it.

Comment: If you create the method in a different class and mark the method as REQUIRES_NEW - and then when you call this method from your current class, do the loops work fine? I am trying this and only iteration of the loop executes and then it pretty much stops. Why is that? Did you face that as well?